# In an interface: Specify implemented method must take a subtype of an interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I want to have an interface specify that any implementations of that interface must use a subtype of a specific interface in their method declaration:

```
interface IModel {} // The original type

interface IMapper {
    void Create(IModel model); // The interface method
}
```

So now I want my implementation of this interface to expect not `IModel` itself, but a *subtype* of `IModel`:

```
public class Customer : IModel {} // My subtype

public class CustomerMapper : IMapper {
    public void Create(Customer customer) {} // Implementation using the subtype
}
```

At the moment I'm getting the following error:

> 'CustomerMapper' does not implement interface member 'IMapper.Create(IModel)'

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make your interface generic in the type of value it should expect:

```
interface IMapper<T> where T : IModel
{
    void Create(T model);
}

...

public class CustomerMapper : IMapper<Customer>
{
    public void Create(Customer model) {}
}
```

If you don't make it generic, anything which only knows about the interface couldn't know what kind of model would be valid.

Comment: Ah! Exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know how to search for that syntax. Do I have to call the argument the same in both places? Or can I call it "model" in the interface and "customer" in the implementation?

Comment: I just tried it, it seems to work with a different argument name

Comment: @RobinWinslow: You *can* change the parameter name, but be aware that that will break the Liskov Substitution Principle if callers use named arguments.

Comment: Are there any situations in which this would break actual code?